# Select data-driven approach for iPad application

Tags: ipad

I have a new iPad application that is data driven (read, delete, create, update) and requires data persistence on iPad devices that are installed the application. There are about 10 tables for that application; those 10 tables are relational in some ways (one to many; many to many; and stand alone). I am new to data driven application with iPad.

I do not know whether I should follow the Core Data approach or SQLite approach. Which approach is the better and real-world oriented?  Please advise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is try both; sketch out two simple versions of your app, one with each implementation. Of course Core Data uses SQLite as storage behind the scenes, but it is much more than that. In my view it's a very complex, clunky beast to wrangle, but it is about modeling and persisting objects that have attributes, it can help a lot with consistency when you delete an object that's involved in a relationship, and the NSFetchedResultsController is helpful for populating a UITableView in a memory-efficient way. With SQLite it's just a database and that's all it is; you have to do all the work, but there are nice Objective-C front ends, and you are completely in control rather than having to do everything in Core Data's very strange way.

There's a short section of my book that demonstrates a tiny Core Data app, and even though it's tiny you can see I spend a lot of time banging my head against the wall of Core Data's special way of doing things:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_core_data

The previous section has a few lines showing how simple it is to fetch data from a SQLite database with a nice Objective-C front end:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_sqlite

I recommend that you read a book about Core Data before you commit yourself to it. There are several good ones. I'm not saying it's bad, but it is not at all a beginner technology and you really need to know what you're in for.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with Core Data in my opinion, what you need to ask yourself is how your data is being used against the benefits of each approach.  Core data lets you update and write data using data types like NSDictionaries which do not require any outside of the box techniques to handle and write data like SQLite does.  SQLite does work and can work how you want it to, but in my opinion using a third party wrapper is just one more step to take to achieve something that is already native.